# is it bad form to have your continuous integration system commit to a repository

Tags: continuous-integration

I have recently been charged with building out our "software infrastructure" and so I am putting together a continuous integration server.

After a build completes would it be considered bad form for the CI system to check in some of the artifacts it creates into a tag so that it can be fetched easily later (or if the build breaks you can more easily recreate the problem.)

For the record we use SVN and BuildMaster (free edition) here.

This is more of a best practices question rather than a how-to question.  (It is pretty easy to do with BuildMaster)

Seth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you believe this approach would be beneficial to you, go ahead and do it. As long as you maintain a clear trace of what source code was used to build each artifact, you'll be fine.

You should keep this artifact repository separated from the source code repository.

It is however a little odd to use a source code repository for this - these are typically used for things that will *change*, something your artifacts most definitely *should not*.

Source code repositories are also often used in a context where you want to check out "everything", for example the entire trunk. With artifacts you are typically looking for a specific version, and checking out all of the would only be done if exporting them to some other medium.

There are several artifact repositories specialized for this, for example [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactory_opensource_overview) or [Apache Archiva](http://archiva.apache.org/), but a properly backed up file server will thought-through access settings might be a simple and good-enough solution.

Comment: Not sure why one would use file server when both repository managers you mentioned are no-brainer in terms of installation and usage and open-source?

Comment: @JBaruch: I can imagine an organization where a file server is already available, but getting approval to run a new software might find organizational resistance (security updates, backups...). I don't say that a file server solution is better in any way, just that it should be included in the cost/benefit analysis.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it's a smell to check in binaries as a tag. Your build artifacts should be associated with a particular build version in your build system, and that build should be associated with a particular checkin. You should be able to recreate the exact source code from that information. If what you're looking for is a one-stop-function to open the precise source-code revision that generated the broken build, I'd suggest that you invest some time into building a Powershell module that will do that for you.

Something with a signature like:
OpenBuild -projectName "some project name" -buildNumber "some build number"

Comment: Chris.  This is a great idea and I will, in fact, be doing something like it.  (Although I will be using MSBuild to accomplish it rather than powershell).